# upgrades to features advice

Tags: 2013

I created a solution a while back that incorporated a number of features and this was deployed to our farm successfully, recently i created some updates and used the feature upgrading event which was ok.  However this raised some questions in my head that i would like advice on.

if i have 2 farms with the solution deployed.  The 1st farm is using version 2.0 and the 2nd is using version 1.0.  I have been tasked with creating some more updates which will be version 3.0 and also to update both farms to this version.  It seems to me to update the 2nd farm to version 3.0 i first need to upgrade to version 2.0 and then upgrade to version 3.0.  Is there a way  that upgrading to version 3.0 will also apply the updates from version 2.0.

The solution to this also has to update the 1st farm to version 3.0 and that it already has version 2.0 installed

Comment: Is v3.0 includes the features of v2.0 and v1.0 (I mean is it a super set?)

Comment: they are all in the same solution.  Basically how can i upgrade to v3.0 and run an upgrade that picks up v2.0 as well.  I dont want to have to upgrade to the v2.0 solution and then run an upgrade and then update the solution to v3.0 and run another update

Comment: If its the super set then you can deploy v3.0 and upgrade it and it will work.

Comment: can you give more of an explanation.  Im not sure i rellay understand

Comment: if v3.0 includes all features that are part of 1 and 2 then directly upgrading (installing) 3.0 will not cause any issues.

Comment: yes but its my understanding that installing v3 and running an upgrade will not install the changes for v2.  only the changes added for v3 will be installed